# It's possible to migrate only products on Magento 1 to 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Our situation's next, I have a Magento 1.9 store live and we are developing a new store in Magento 2. The new store it's a new clean versión of the site and we only have to migrate products, categories, and attributes (we don't need orders, for example).

We only have Amasty layered navigation module installed, but if it's a problem we can restore a clean installation.

There's a tool to do this? I can't find if Magento's official Data Migration Tool has this option.

Comment: migrate everything then delete customers and orders...

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar requirement and I was able to achieve it using the solution provided at https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/406#issuecomment-342501646

Comment: hi @Anshu mishra, can we migrate only products and customers without orders?

Comment: @jafar pinjar yes, you can migrate only products and customers without orders.

Comment: ok thanks, can you explain me what need to be done for that?

Comment: @jafarpinjar check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate.html

Comment: yes, this link i referred and got to know how to do migration process, but i am asking how to migrate only customers and products? have you done this? If yes please share the ideas..

Comment: @jafarpinjar you have to do the configuration in config.xml in the tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92492/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-anshu-mishra).

Comment: hi @Ashu Mishra, Please share the idea on how to migrate only Products.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you:

- Follow the migration document of Magento here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html. However, you really need to know techniques to move data to Magento 2 manually.
- Find a reliable automated shopping cart data migration service/ experienced data migration experts to help you transfer all your data automatically from your current store on Magento to the new version. This solution helps you to save a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely YES**, you can use any kind of data integration software that can connect to MySQL Magento 1 database and then export it to the import format of Magento 2. After that, you can import that product data from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

If you do not want to use the import/export tool, you can use [Magento 2 Integration by Beehexa](https://www.beehexa.com/magento-2-integration/)

I am pretty sure that It can connect to M1 Database then creating product data in M2 via [Magento 2 API](https://www.beehexa.com/devdocs/magento-2-api-create-products-with-postman/)

We really hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar upgrade a while ago. My solution was to upgrade the Magento instance on a separate installation, then export the relevant tables (products, attributes, stock etc) into an SQL dump and import them into the new installations DB. You should then have one Magento installation with the product data, but without orders/customers/invoices etc

Hope that helps!